# How to limit 10 concurrent sessions/connections in nodeJS Application

Tags: node.js, session, express-session

I am working on NodeJS (middleware used- Express-session, session-file-store) application where I have defined user permissions as- 'view', 'view-edit' and 'edit'. This application should have max total active session or active user count to be 10.

Should I use session count? I have to maxAge of session limiting to 5 min.

So problem is after a session is expired then session count should be updated. but once session is expired I can't traces it..

Comment: can you post code.

Comment: var sess_options = {
path: "/tmp/sessions/",
useAsync: true
};
router.use(session({
store: new FileStore(sess_options),
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false,
secret: 'asts123',
rolling : false,
cookie: { httpOnly: false,
secure: true,
maxAge: 60000}
}));
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
if (typeof req.session.user_mode === 'undefined') {
 session_ids.push(req.session.id);
 res.app.locals.session_count++;
 req.session.user_mode = 'view_mode';
}}
Now I don't know how to decrement the session count when session expires, as to know how many active sessions are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution to get the session count if we are using file-session-store in node.js

```
//file store parameters
var sess_options = {
path: "/tmp/sessions/",
useAsync: true
};
// sess_count variable
var sess_count = 0;

var file_store = new FileStore(sess_options);
router.use(session({
  store : file_store,
  resave : false,
  saveUninitialized : true,
  secret : 'asts123',
 rolling : false,
cookie : {  httpOnly: false,
secure : true,
maxAge : 60000
}
}));

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
file_store.length(function session_count(a,len) {
  sess_count = len;
  console.log("Total active session count is " + sess_count);
  console.log("============");
});
 return next();
});
```